# I am using a bootstrap modal window to display user alert. I am trying to call the modal window from different places and assigned different content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" data- 
keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title"id="myModalTitle">Alias Name</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myModalContent">
            <p>Do you want your First Name as Alias Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button id="myModalButtonYes" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
            <button id="myModalButtonNo" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
   dismiss="modal" >No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#myModalTitle').text('Duplicate Patient');
            $('#myModalContent').text('A patient already exists with the same name and 
birthdate. Do you want to continue?');
            const btn = document.getElementById("myModalButtonNo")
            btn.addEventListener("click", DuplicateName())
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

        });
```

I wanted to call different functions when modal Ok button is clciked in different scenarios.
btn.addEventListener("click", DuplicateName()) didnot work and also document.getElementById("myModalButtonNo").onclick = DuplicateName() didnot work.

Please give me your suggestions on this.

Comment: `btn.addEventListener("click", DuplicateName())` seems like a mistake, you shouldn't be calling the function with the ()

Answer (score 0):

you change the modal text but the button is static try to call the function in the HTML button element.

```
<button id="myModalButtonYes" onclick="DuplicateName()" type="button" 
class="btn btn-primary" data- 
dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
```